# Passing details to popup window using Selenium (C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, popup

I am trying to pass Details like FirstName, LastName etc to the popup window. I am attaching the screenshot as well. The problem I am facing is the field name of the LastName is same as the main window, so when I am trying to pass the details, it is getting added to the main window instead of the popup window.
The C# code that I am using is:

```
var w = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
var copy =w.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("copyButton")));
copy.Click();
Driver.Instance.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.Instance.WindowHandles.Last());
Driver.Instance.Manage().Window.Maximize();
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Name("lastname")).SendKeys("Emily");
```

Here instead of passing to the popup window, it is passing to the main window.

I have also tried to inspect in the popup and tried to copy the xpath:

```
var w = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
var copy =w.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("copyButton")));
copy.Click();
Driver.Instance.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.Instance.WindowHandles.Last());
Driver.Instance.Manage().Window.Maximize();
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*  [@id="pageBodyNoHeader"]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).SendKeys("Emily");
```

Over here it says "Syntax error(,) is expected".

Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: Have you tied using single quotes in the Xpath query? `Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[@id='pageBodyNoHeader']/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).SendKeys("Emily");`

Comment: **Adrija**: Please review the answers to this question and your past 13 questions with no accepts and accept those answers that have helped you most (and upvote those that are useful). Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to Solve your Syntax issue, simply change:

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*  [@id="pageBodyNoHeader"]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).SendKeys("Emily");
```

To:

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*  [@id='pageBodyNoHeader']/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).SendKeys("Emily");
```

Comment: No problem, if this has resolved your problem please mark this as answered. Glad i could help

Comment: :)

To accept an answer:
Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.